# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with multiple view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've tried to develop a multi view controller app and I have this error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lbl_nbVies: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_motCache: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_lettreSaisies: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txt_proposition: UITextField!

// Déclaration des variables
var nbVies: Int = 11

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Affichage du nombre de vie dans le label "lbl_nbVies"
    lbl_nbVies.text = "Test"
    lbl_motCache.text = ""
    lbl_lettreSaisies.text = ""
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/* Action lorsque l'on appuie sur le bouton tester */
@IBAction func btn_tester(sender: AnyObject) {

}

/* Action lorsque l'on appuie sur le bouton vider */
@IBAction func btn_vider(sender: AnyObject) {
    txt_proposition.text = ""
}

}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code that you have posted does not indicate where you are seeing the error, nor does it contain any Optional values. Please update your question or correct your sample code.

Comment: I have the error at line: lbl_nbVies.text = "Test"

Answer (score 0):

This can mean that you are trying to call a function of an object which is not initialized.

My guess is that one or several of your outlets are not initialized. So, when your call `lbl_nbVies.text`, you are calling `text` function on a `nil` outlet.

Make sure that your outlets are hooked up properly in the storyboard (you should see a circle near your `@IBOutlet`).

Comment: They are hooked up properly

Answer (score 0):

This means that `lbl_nbVies` isn't initialised. However if you're creating IBOutlets then they should be set up. One things I've seen people do is create multiple connections to the object (in your course case the label) in interface builder.

Make sure you haven't accidentally set up multiple connections. Select the label in you're nib or storyboard can check the connections inspector.

[image]

Comment: There is only 1 connection that reference the View Controller

Comment: In which case, I'd try deleting the IBOutlet and and the label in interface builder and start again.